# Dropdown Boxes Not Responding

Tags: html, responsive-design, dropdownbox

All of a sudden, these 3 dropdown boxes I have on my home page stopped responding. I feel like I'm going crazy and just not able to figure it out. Code is below.

[I have 3 boxes that contain tables that are revealed on click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLcJ6.png). However, they are not revealing. [They should look like this when clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbjuZ.png).

The website is [thrivematching.com](http://thrivematching.com) if you need to check it out. It was working not too long ago, so not sure what happened. The hamburger menu (on mobile) also stop working. Seems like a joint issue, but not sure?

HTML for 3 Dropdown Tables:

```html
<div
    class="accordion mt-5"
    id="scenarios"
    role="tablist"
    aria-multiselectable="true"
>
    <div class="panel-primary mb-3">
        <div class="text-white" role="tab" id="studentHeading">
            <h4>
                <button
                    class="w-100 p-4 btn-primary text-center"
                    data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-parent="#scenarios"
                    data-target="#student"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-controls="student"
                >
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                        <div class="col-10 text-center text-sm-left">
                            <span>100% Student Loan Contribution</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2 h-100 my-auto">
                            <span
                                class="symbol rounded-circle d-block ml-auto"
                            ></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </button>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div
            id="student"
            class="rounded panel-collapse collapse"
            role="tabpanel"
            aria-labelledby="studentHeading"
        >
            <h5 class="text-center pt-5 mx-3">
                Employer contributes <strong>$0</strong> to employee retirement
                plan and <strong>$3,000</strong> to student loans annually.
            </h5>
            <div class="mr-3">
                <table
                    class="table justify-content-center text-center text-white round-table mt-5 mb-2 table-responsive-sm"
                >
                    <caption>
                        <span class="sr-only"
                            >100% Student Loan Contribution</span
                        >
                    </caption>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="pr-4"></td>
                            <th scope="col">Retirement Plan</th>
                            <th scope="col">Student Loan</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" class="pr-4">
                                Employee Contributes
                            </th>
                            <td>0%</td>
                            <td>5% ($250/month)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" class="pr-4">Employer Match</th>
                            <td>0%</td>
                            <td>5% ($250/month)</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-secondary mb-3">
        <div class="text-white" role="tab" id="retirementHeading">
            <h4>
                <button
                    class="w-100 p-4 btn-secondary text-center"
                    data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-parent="#scenarios"
                    data-target="#retirement"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-controls="retirement"
                >
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                        <div class="col-10 text-center text-sm-left">
                            <span>100% Retirement Plan Contribution</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2 h-100 my-auto">
                            <span
                                class="symbol rounded-circle d-block ml-auto"
                            ></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </button>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div
            id="retirement"
            class="panel-collapse collapse rounded"
            role="tabpanel"
            aria-labelledby="retirementHeading"
        >
            <h5 class="text-center pt-5 mx-3">
                Employer contributes <strong>$0</strong> to employee student
                loans and <strong>$3,000</strong> to retirement plan annually.
            </h5>
            <div class="mr-3">
                <table
                    class="table w-100 justify-content-center text-center text-white round-table mt-5 mb-2 table-responsive-sm"
                >
                    <caption>
                        <span class="sr-only"
                            >100% Retirement Plan Contribution</span
                        >
                    </caption>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="pr-4"></td>
                            <th scope="col">Retirement Plan</th>
                            <th scope="col">Student Loan</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" class="pr-4">
                                Employee Contributes
                            </th>
                            <td>5% ($250/month)</td>
                            <td>0%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" class="pr-4">Employer Match</th>
                            <td>5% ($250/month)</td>
                            <td>0%</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-support mb-3">
        <div class="text-white" role="tab" id="splitHeading">
            <h4>
                <button
                    class="w-100 p-4 btn-support text-center"
                    data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-parent="#scenarios"
                    data-target="#split"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-controls="split"
                >
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                        <div class="col-10 text-center text-sm-left">
                            <span>Retirement Plan/Student Loan Split</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2 h-100 my-auto">
                            <span
                                class="symbol rounded-circle d-block ml-auto"
                            ></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </button>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div
            id="split"
            class="panel-collapse collapse rounded"
            role="tabpanel"
            aria-labelledby="splitHeading"
        >
            <h5 class="text-center pt-5 mx-3">
                Employer contributes <strong>$1,800</strong> to employee
                retirement plan and <strong>$1,200</strong> to student loans
                annually. Retirement plan contributions must be matched before
                student loan contributions can be applied.
            </h5>
            <div class="mr-3">
                <table
                    class="table w-100 justify-content-center text-center text-white round-table mt-5 mb-2 table-responsive-sm"
                >
                    <caption>
                        <span class="sr-only"
                            >Retirement Plan/Student Loan Split</span
                        >
                    </caption>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="pr-4"></td>
                            <th scope="col">Retirement Plan</th>
                            <th scope="col">Student Loan</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" class="pr-4">
                                Employee Contributes
                            </th>
                            <td>3% ($150/month)</td>
                            <td>5% ($250/month)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" class="pr-4">Employer Match</th>
                            <td>3% ($150/month)</td>
                            <td>2% ($100/month)</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your code out using Bootstrap 4 and it seemed to work just fine. Are you using Bootstrap 4? The link to your site doesn't work so I couldn't investigate further.

Comment: @MichaelvE I am not using Bootstrap 4. The site is being directed to a new IP address. Once that is settled and loads, I will test again. I might reach back out and see if we can get this figured out with any advice from you. Stay tuned and thank you!

Comment: @MichaelvE the site is up and live again (thrivematching.com) if you can check that out and shed any insight on why the hamburger menu, dropdown boxes in the screenshot, etc. isn't responding, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your site does not appear to use Bootstrap as I thought it might do, but it does use a library that seems to be based on Bootstrap because it is filled with the same class names that Bootstrap uses. It's difficult to find the source of your problem, but we can make a start. For starters, the site is not finding a JavaScript file called https://youbenefited.com/wp-content/cache/min/1/14a61199fa0e837e4bfec0d4bbe5f4bd.js Your problem might be solved by simply correcting the path so that your page can find this JS file. Start with that, and then let's see what happens once that is corrected.

Comment: Perfect! This site is based off of another and has JS linked in it. Looks like that link changed in the original. So I went to the new JS source, copy/pasted into my own .js file and put it in my root file so it can't be changed.

Thanks for taking a look! Saved me a headache!